# Why Invoice state goes directly to paid instead of open from draft?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am trying to make invoices in Odoo v10. When I am logged in as Administrator and make invoice, the invoice go from `draft` to `open` state. But when i am logged in as some other user, invoice state goes from `draft` to `paid` state directly without going into `paid` state.

What could be the reason for this??

[image: Using this invoice form]

using the above form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. Actually I made a mistake. While adding an invoice line I added a account of type receivable. So, it was going directly to paid state.

Receivable/payable account types in invoice lines

[image] will take the invoice to `paid` state directly while other types will take it to `open` state.

So, I just changed the account type and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suppose that you are modifying this module or it's behavior, so you probably are messing with some of the basic methods. For example

#### Validate

The basic behavior of **validate** for **account_invoice** is here, you can see that it returns a **open** state
[addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L923](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3678cffcf940f699b29630c3ac3f5427a3cdf9f7/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L916)

#### A couple of questions:

- what button is giving you this behavior?
- are you modifying a method?
- can you share more information, a video maybe?
- if you are modifying explain what method and what does it do please

Comment: no, I've not changed any code, not even a single line. Is there any access right that might be responsible for this?

Comment: can you add a video of that feature? just to see the process you are using, also, you are an administrator or a user when doing the video? thanks and regards